# How to fix the inconsistent naming convention of embedded resources in vNext?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

As far as I can tell the `project.json` file has taken over handling the majority of properties for any given file in a project in VS2015. I've setup a project to embed files into my assembly as follows, however the resulting naming convention of the embedded resources is a departure from what is produced by the previous versions of the c# compiler.

In current state resources are embedded using the `period` as a separator and included the Assembly name at the beginning like: `ClassLibrary3.Templates.dashboard.html`

In vNext embedded resource names are produced using the forward slash as a separator and do not include the Assembly's name; well sometimes. See the accompanying picture below. `.resx` files seem to follow the old pattern while anything defined in the `project.json` is something totally new.

Can I control the naming convention with a setting somewhere? Is this a bug, feature, or a `todo`? I need something consistent.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "resource": ["Templates/**/*.*"], // embed everything beneath this folder

  "dependencies": {
  },

  "frameworks" : {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50" : {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a known issue for `beta4` and below. It has been fixed in `beta5`. The names are now identical to the ones generated by MsBuild, with a few exceptions.

The most notable exception is that MsBuild ignores the "Resources" folder from the name. For example:

`Class1/Resources/x.resx -> Class1.x.resources`

while in ASP.NET 5 we have:

`Class1/Resources/x.resx -> Class1.Resources.x.resources`

For that, we've added support for [named resources](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Core/project.json#L17-L19). They are useful in scenarios where you want to share resources between multiple projects, including the resource readers OR in PCL scenarios.